# The job listing does not work properly when sorted by date

Tags: php, wordpress-rest-api

I'm modifying a plugin that uses an API to connect to LOXO. The job listing works fine, but I'm trying to sort it by date... so that it lists the jobs from the most recent to the oldest. However, pagination is giving me trouble... when I tell it to list the jobs with a limit of 10 records per page, they don't appear sorted. Here's my code, which is part of a plugin that connects with LOXO.

My code below edited / updated

```
<section id="limestaff-job-search">
    <h3>Job Search</h3>   
    <?php require 'top-search.php'; ?>

    <div class="jobs-wrapper">
        <?php if (empty($jobs)): ?>
            <h4>No Jobs Found</h4>
            
            
        <?php else:  ?>
            <?php $currencies=[["id"=>1,"code"=>"USD","symbol"=>"$"],["id"=>2,"code"=>"EUR","symbol"=>"€"],["id"=>3,"code"=>"JPY","symbol"=>"¥"],["id"=>4,"code"=>"GBP","symbol"=>"£"],["id"=>5,"code"=>"AUD","symbol"=>"A$"],["id"=>6,"code"=>"CAD","symbol"=>"C$"],["id"=>7,"code"=>"CHF","symbol"=>"CHf"],["id"=>8,"code"=>"CNY","symbol"=>"元"],["id"=>9,"code"=>"SEK","symbol"=>"kr"],["id"=>10,"code"=>"NZD","symbol"=>"NZ$"],["id"=>11,"code"=>"MXN","symbol"=>"$"],["id"=>12,"code"=>"SGD","symbol"=>"S$"],["id"=>13,"code"=>"HKD","symbol"=>"HK$"],["id"=>14,"code"=>"NOK","symbol"=>"kr"],["id"=>15,"code"=>"KRW","symbol"=>"₩"],["id"=>16,"code"=>"TRY","symbol"=>"₺"],["id"=>17,"code"=>"RUB","symbol"=>"₽"],["id"=>18,"code"=>"INR","symbol"=>"₹"],["id"=>19,"code"=>"BRL","symbol"=>"R$"],["id"=>20,"code"=>"ZAR","symbol"=>"R"],["id"=>21,"code"=>"CZK","symbol"=>"Kč"],["id"=>22,"code"=>"ILS","symbol"=>"₪"],["id"=>23,"code"=>"PLN","symbol"=>"zł"],["id"=>24,"code"=>"AED","symbol"=>"إ.د"],["id"=>25,"code"=>"SAR","symbol"=>"﷼"],["id"=>26,"code"=>"DKK","symbol"=>"Kr."],["id"=>27,"code"=>"BGN","symbol"=>"лв."],["id"=>28,"code"=>"THB","symbol"=>"฿"],["id"=>29,"code"=>"KWD","symbol"=>"KD, د.ك"],["id"=>30,"code"=>"MYR","symbol"=>"RM"],["id"=>31,"code"=>"PEN","symbol"=>"S/"],["id"=>33,"code"=>"PHP","symbol"=>"₱"],["id"=>34,"code"=>"IDR","symbol"=>"Rp"],["id"=>35,"code"=>"TWD","symbol"=>"NT$"]];?>
            <?php 
            


                    // Number of records per page
                    $limit = 10;
                    // Current page number
                    $page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 1;
                    // Calculate the starting index for the current page
                   $start = ($page - 1) * $limit;
                  // Calculate total number of pages
                   // $totalPages = ceil(count($jobs) / $limit);
         
                  
                   $dates = array();
                   foreach ($jobs as $jobx) {
                          $dates[] = $jobx->published_at;
                   }
                   rsort($dates);
                   
             
                   foreach ($dates as $sortedDate) {
                       echo date('m/d/Y', strtotime($sortedDate)).'<br>';
                   }   
                   
                       
                 
                  // Use the sorted 'published_at' values in the loop   
                        foreach ($dates as $sortedDate):
                           // Find the corresponding job using the sorted date
                             foreach ($jobs as $job):
                                if ($job->published_at  === $sortedDate):
                                     
                                                     
                                         $currencyId = $job->salary_currency_id;
                                         $matchingCurrency = array_filter($currencies, function ($currency) use ($currencyId) {
                                         return $currency['id'] == $currencyId;
                                                           });
                                         $selectedCurrency = reset($matchingCurrency);
                                     
                                     ?>
                                       <!--   <h3> <?php // echo  $job->title. ' - ' .date('m/d/Y', strtotime($job->published_at));   break;    ?> </h3> -->
                                       
                                            <article class="job" data-job="<?Php echo $job->id; ?>">
                                            <a href="<?php echo $this->job_url_builder(get_permalink(), 'job', $job->id); ?>">
                                            <h4>  <?php echo $job->title; ?>  </h4>
                                            <div class="job-meta">
                                            
                                                   <?php if ($render_settings['view_toggles']['location']): ?>
                                                        <span class="location">
                                                            <?php echo !empty($job->macro_address) ? $job->macro_address : 'No Location'; ?>
                                                        </span>
                                                   <?php endif; ?>
                                                   <?php if ($render_settings['view_toggles']['salary']): ?>
                                                          <span class="salary">
                                                              <?php
                                    
                                                                  $originalValue = $job->salary;
                                                                  if (str_contains($originalValue, 'year')) {  
                                                                         list($minPart, $maxPart) = explode(' - ', $originalValue);
                                                                         $min = filter_var($minPart, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
                                                                         $max = filter_var($maxPart, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
                                                                         $formattedRange = "$" . $min . "-" . $max . "k/year";
                                                                         echo !empty($formattedRange)
                                                                          ? $formattedRange
                                                                          : 'No Salary';
                                                                          
                                                                  } else {
                                                                      
                                                                         list($minPart, $maxPart) = explode(' - ', $originalValue);
                                                                         $min = filter_var($minPart, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
                                                                         $max = filter_var($maxPart, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
                                                                         $formattedRange = "$" . $min . "-" . $max . "/hour";
                                                                         echo !empty($formattedRange)
                                                                          ? $formattedRange
                                                                          : 'No Salary';
                                                                      }
                                                                 //echo !empty($job->salary)
                                                                //  ? $selectedCurrency['symbol'] . $job->salary
                                                               //   : 'No Salary';  
                                                               ?>
                                                           </span>
                                                   <?php endif; ?>
                                                   <?php if ($render_settings['view_toggles']['job_type']): ?>
                                                          <span class="type">
                                                                 <?Php echo $job->job_type->name; ?>
                                                                 
                                                          </span>
                                                   <?php endif; ?>
                                                    <?php if ($render_settings['view_toggles']['job_type']): ?>
                                                          <span class="type">
                                                                 <?Php echo date('m/d/Y', strtotime($job->published_at)); ?>
                                                                 
                                                          </span>
                                                   <?php endif; ?>

                                            </div>
                                            </a>
                                            </article>
                
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>





        <?php endif; ?>


                    </div> <!-- el codigo va abajo -->  
      
                    <?php if ($total_pages > 1): ?>
                            <nav class="jobs-pagination">
                                  <?php if ($current_page > 1): ?>
                                     <a href="<?php echo $this->job_url_builder(get_permalink(), 'jobs_page', ($current_page - 1)); ?>">
                                     << </a>
                                  <?php endif; ?>
                                  <?php $i = 1;
                                       while ($i <= $total_pages): ?>
                                               <a href="<?php echo $this->job_url_builder(get_permalink(), 'jobs_page', $i); ?>"
                                                     class="<?php echo (int) $current_page === $i ? 'active' : ''; ?>">
                                              <?php echo $i; ?>
                                               </a>
                                  <?php
                                          $i++;
                                        endwhile;
                     ?>
                                  <?php if ($has_more_pages): ?>
                                         <a
                                            href="<?php echo $this->job_url_builder(get_permalink(), 'jobs_page', ($current_page + 1)); ?>">>></a>
                                 <?php endif; ?>
                           </nav>
                    <?php endif; ?>


</section>
```

The original plugin code below

```
<section id="limestaff-job-search">
   <h3>Job Search</h3>
   <?php require 'top-search.php'; ?>
   <div class="jobs-wrapper">
       <?php if (empty($jobs)): ?>
           <h4>No Jobs Found</h4>
       <?php else: ?>
           <?php $currencies=[["id"=>1,"code"=>"USD","symbol"=>"$"],["id"=>2,"code"=>"EUR","symbol"=>"€"],["id"=>3,"code"=>"JPY","symbol"=>"¥"],["id"=>4,"code"=>"GBP","symbol"=>"£"],["id"=>5,"code"=>"AUD","symbol"=>"A$"],["id"=>6,"code"=>"CAD","symbol"=>"C$"],["id"=>7,"code"=>"CHF","symbol"=>"CHf"],["id"=>8,"code"=>"CNY","symbol"=>"元"],["id"=>9,"code"=>"SEK","symbol"=>"kr"],["id"=>10,"code"=>"NZD","symbol"=>"NZ$"],["id"=>11,"code"=>"MXN","symbol"=>"$"],["id"=>12,"code"=>"SGD","symbol"=>"S$"],["id"=>13,"code"=>"HKD","symbol"=>"HK$"],["id"=>14,"code"=>"NOK","symbol"=>"kr"],["id"=>15,"code"=>"KRW","symbol"=>"₩"],["id"=>16,"code"=>"TRY","symbol"=>"₺"],["id"=>17,"code"=>"RUB","symbol"=>"₽"],["id"=>18,"code"=>"INR","symbol"=>"₹"],["id"=>19,"code"=>"BRL","symbol"=>"R$"],["id"=>20,"code"=>"ZAR","symbol"=>"R"],["id"=>21,"code"=>"CZK","symbol"=>"Kč"],["id"=>22,"code"=>"ILS","symbol"=>"₪"],["id"=>23,"code"=>"PLN","symbol"=>"zł"],["id"=>24,"code"=>"AED","symbol"=>"إ.د"],["id"=>25,"code"=>"SAR","symbol"=>"﷼"],["id"=>26,"code"=>"DKK","symbol"=>"Kr."],["id"=>27,"code"=>"BGN","symbol"=>"лв."],["id"=>28,"code"=>"THB","symbol"=>"฿"],["id"=>29,"code"=>"KWD","symbol"=>"KD, د.ك"],["id"=>30,"code"=>"MYR","symbol"=>"RM"],["id"=>31,"code"=>"PEN","symbol"=>"S/"],["id"=>33,"code"=>"PHP","symbol"=>"₱"],["id"=>34,"code"=>"IDR","symbol"=>"Rp"],["id"=>35,"code"=>"TWD","symbol"=>"NT$"]];?>
           <?php 
               foreach ($jobs as $job):
                   $currencyId = $job->salary_currency_id;
                   $matchingCurrency = array_filter($currencies, function ($currency) use ($currencyId) {
                       return $currency['id'] == $currencyId;
                   });
                   $selectedCurrency = reset($matchingCurrency);
           ?>

               <article class="job" data-job="<?Php echo $job->id; ?>">
                   <a href="<?php echo $this->job_url_builder(get_permalink(), 'job', $job->id); ?>">
                       <h4>
                           <?php echo $job->title; ?>
                       </h4>
                       <div class="job-meta">
                           <?php if ($render_settings['view_toggles']['location']): ?>
                               <span class="location">
                                   <?php echo !empty($job->macro_address) ? $job->macro_address : 'No Location'; ?>
                               </span>
                           <?php endif; ?>
                           <?php if ($render_settings['view_toggles']['salary']): ?>
                               <span class="salary">
                                   <?php
                                   echo !empty($job->salary)
                                       ? $selectedCurrency['symbol'] . $job->salary
                                       : 'No Salary';
                                   ?>
                               </span>
                           <?php endif; ?>
                           <?php if ($render_settings['view_toggles']['job_type']): ?>
                               <span class="type">
                                   <?Php echo $job->job_type->name; ?>
                               </span>
                           <?php endif; ?>
                       </div>
                   </a>
               </article>
           <?php endforeach; ?>
       <?php endif; ?>
   </div>
   <?php if ($total_pages > 1): ?>
       <nav class="jobs-pagination">
           <?php if ($current_page > 1): ?>
               <a href="<?php echo $this->job_url_builder(get_permalink(), 'jobs_page', ($current_page - 1)); ?>">
                   <<< /a>
                   <?php endif; ?>
                   <?php $i = 1;
                   while ($i <= $total_pages): ?>
                       <a href="<?php echo $this->job_url_builder(get_permalink(), 'jobs_page', $i); ?>"
                           class="<?php echo (int) $current_page === $i ? 'active' : ''; ?>">
                           <?php echo $i; ?>
                       </a>
                       <?php
                       $i++;
                   endwhile;
                   ?>
                   <?php if ($has_more_pages): ?>
                       <a
                           href="<?php echo $this->job_url_builder(get_permalink(), 'jobs_page', ($current_page + 1)); ?>">>></a>
                   <?php endif; ?>
       </nav>
   <?php endif; ?>
</section>
```

Comment: It looks like `$jobs` is already a paginated segment of the data only. So the plugin gives you the first X posts in its original sort order - which you then sort by date. Going to the next page, gives you the next X posts, again in the plugin's sort order ... which means, you can't do it this way. Check the plugin docs / code, whether it offers settings or hooks for this purpose. Or, if not, see if the `pre_get_posts` filter allows you to identify the query in any way, so that you can manipulate the sort order via that.

Comment: @CBroe If I believe I should implement internal pagination. This code is a widget ...and the default widget comes with the option to limit the records per page. But it's not something that happens within the code, it's done outside of this code section.